# How to version a C# interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I have a C# interface, `IFoo`, which can be implemented by multiple parties in multiple projects. What I want to do is version the interface so that I can identify which version of the interface an implementation was developed against.

Is there a preferred/conventional way of doing this? I thought about putting a read-only `InterfaceVersion` property into the interface spec, but that can be defined by the implementer, not by me as the designer of the interface, and so isn't what I want.

Comment: I would version the library its in and go from there.

Comment: public interface IFoo_v2 { } ?

Comment: This comment may not be entirely helpful, but creating different versions of an interface is probably not a good idea. Interfaces are useful because they ensure complete compatibility between classes that are based off the same interface. In normal circumstances, an interface does not get changed anymore once its being used in implementations.

Comment: I think you are missing the point of interfaces.  The whole idea is that they should not change, but that the implementation of them should change.  This requires good analysis and design work up front.  Understandably, occasionally they will need to change, but this should be the exception not the norm.

Comment: @ken4z There are cases when developing extensible applications where any alteration to the assembly containing the interface definitions will render the entire extension mechanism permanently inoperable. In these cases, there can never be a need for change.

Comment: @280Z28 I think we are in agreement that interfaces shouldn't change.  My only caveat to that is that they CAN change, but there are often significant costs to doing so and those costs need to factor into a business's decision on whether to do so or not.  For instance, typically updating the major version of your code indicates that there are breaking changes in the release.

Comment: @ken4z As detailed in my answer, there actually are cases where you cannot update the major version of your code. Or even the revision number for that matter. *Any* change to *any* part of the strong-named assembly would wreck havoc on the application's extension mechanism. Since the OP suggested the assembly containing the interfaces would be used by other projects, I want to make sure to mention this critical detail, as it's too late to address it down the road when you find out the hard way.

Comment: Jesus - can of philosophical worms opened here. The short answer seems that there is not a short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *very* complicated topic when you consider the full impact of various decisions. I have started the process of documenting this in the following topic:

[Assembly Versioning in Extensible Applications](http://tunnelvisionlabs.github.io/vsbase/docs-master/html/edbfd3ce-43f4-4f3f-a90c-bc22bda19fae.htm)

This document focuses on Visual Studio 2010 and newer, which is itself an extensible application with multiple versions released to date. The extension mechanism in place is MEF, but the rules and restrictions it imposes still apply to other extension mechanisms.

This document is a work-in-progress. Suggestions and/or problems can be reported on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/vsbase/issues).

Answer (score 2):

Typically one doesn't version an interface because it is considered a contract (and contracts should be enforced not broken). Typically a new interface is created with the new functionality (IFoo2 perhaps) and classes that need to participate in the new contract will then implement that.

```
public class Foo : IFoo, IFoo2 
{
    // Implementation goes here
}
```

Comment: I get the whole "an interface is a contract" thing, and used one precisely because I want implementation to be bound to my specification, but I don't want the situation where I have multiple interfaces that are effectively the same thing, maybe just with a couple of new properties in a year's time.

Comment: You can define IFoo2 as requiring IFoo1

Answer (score 0):

> but that can be defined by the implementer, not by me as the designer
>   of the interface, and so isn't what I want

This passage contains the answer to your own question. What you want is something that can only be defined by you (the designer), so it has to be something 100% contained in the assemblies you provide. Assemblies contain types, therefore this something must be a type.

Obviously you cannot change any interface after you have shipped it (that would break the code all your clients), so the only option remaining is to *define a new interface*. Implementers can then opt-in to the new version by choosing to implement it.